# How can you get the coordinates of the "X" button in a window?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wndproc

For one reason or another, I have a need to detect when the user actually clicked on the X button. What I have so far is this:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == (int)0xa1) //WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN
        {
            Point p = new Point((int)m.LParam);
            p = this.PointToClient(p);
            if (p.X > 680)
            {
                //do what I need to do...
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Basically, I look out for the "WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN" message which is the Mouse Click on the Non Client Area of a window. Then, I get the X and Y coordinates from the LParam and finally I convert it to Screen Coordinates. So at this point, I know that the user clicked on the non client area and I know where on the Form.

My question is, how can I tell if these coordinates are on the X button. For now, I'm hardcoding 680 because that's what works in the current size of the window (it's not sizable) but the problem is I'm using Windows 7 which has bigger X buttons than XP, so obviously hardocding isn't a viable option. Furthermore, I haven't even coded for the Y coordinates, so if someone clicks on the right edge of the window, that triggers that code as well. So... anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is the clicking of the button important or are you really trying to see if the user is closing the application?

Comment: Why do you want to handle the "x button" differently than other close/quit messages?

Comment: It's a weird situation, I'll admit, but basically it's a dialog and on closing I want to trigger validation, but the standard FormValidating event isn't working property because it's a Dialog (don't ask, another post for another day, I think it's a bug). So I'm manually handling Validation in the FormClosing event, but I need to know if the user just clicked the X in which case I want to skip the validation. Makes sense?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. There are a number of ways to close the form that have the same effect as pressing the close button and I expect they all suffer the same issue. For instance you can close the form by pressing Alt+F4 or right clicking the title bar and selecting Close Form from the resulting menu. I expect Windows 7 will add a Touch gesture to do the same.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have an OK and a Cancel button, why don't you just set a value when one of these buttons is clicked. Then on the form's Closing event, if this value is not set, you know the X button has been clicked. Unless there are other ways of closing the form I'm not aware of...

Edit:

Instead of using a global boolean, you could change the DialogResult property of the form on your button clicks. I'm not sure what is the DialogResult value when you click the X button though, you'll have to try it.

Comment: Ok, I just re-read your post, and I see what you're saying now. I didn't really want to have to keep booleans around for the buttons that trigger validation. I may end up having to resort to this if there is no other solution. For now I'll keep this question open though, if no one can provide a solution, I'll mark this as accepted. Thanks!. +1

Comment: keeping a flag for needing to validate is hacky, but less hacky than what the OP is originally asking to do.  +1

Comment: You could also use DialogResult instead of booleans, check my edit!

Comment: Set the DialogResult of the form to a default of Cancel in the Load event of the form. Let the default be to not validate since most actions do not validate the form. Then all the other ways of closing should use that.

Answer (score 0):

If you test for the WM_NCHITTEST message that should tell you when the mouse is hovering over the close button.